# Preventing text two pixel shift with hover over or active?

Tags: html, css

I'm creating a basic menu and trying to show a left block two pixels wide when active or hovered.  The problem is that my text is shifting to the right two pixels when active or hovered.

I've created this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/thetoolsmith/psLL5hmx/) to show the issue.

My css looks like this:

```
#sidebar {
  height: 100%;
  padding-right: 0;
  padding-top: 20px;
}

#sidebar .nav {
  width: 95%; 
}

#sidebar li {
}

#sidebar .nav>.active>a, #sidebar .nav>.active:hover>a, #sidebar .nav>.active:focus>a {
  font-weight: 700;
  color: #563d7c;
  background-color: transparent;
  border-left: 2px solid #563d7c;
}

#sidebar .nav>li>a:hover, #sidebar .nav>li>a:focus {
  font-weight: 700;
  color: #563d7c;
  background-color: transparent;
  border-left: 2px solid #563d7c;
}
```

Any idea how I can prevent the text from shifting to the right when hovering over the menu item or when it's selected?

Thanks,
-Paul

Answer (score 6, accepted):

just add a

```
border-left: 2px solid transparent;
```

for the links when they are in the normal state.
On `:hover` you have to only change the `border-color` property (you may also change the colour smoothly, with a simple css transition).

---

Basic Example: http://jsfiddle.net/sLokoys3/

Transition example: http://jsfiddle.net/5Lnytpx9/1/

Comment: Best way to do it, there are other ways like messing with the margin etc but this is a better way.

Comment: That's what I was missing. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
#sidebar .nav>li>a {
    border-left: 2px solid transparent;
}
```

[**jsFiddle example**](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/psLL5hmx/1/)